# checkbox inside Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel (click once to trigger afteredit event)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a checkbox column inside Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel configured like this:

```
{
    id: 'event-type-grid-enabled-checkbox',
    header: "Enabled",
    dataIndex: "enabled",
    sortable: true,
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    editor: {
        xtype:'checkbox',
        name: 'enabled'
    },
    renderer: function(val) {
        return "<input type='checkbox'" + (val ? "checked='checked'" : "") + ">";
    }
}
```

I want to be able to trigger the afteredit event of EditorGridPanel when user checks/unchecks the checkbox. There are other columns (textfields) beside checkbox column and user can double click and edit and they work perfectly fine, afteredit gets triggered and ajax call is made to update data and so on...

when i double click the checkbox then afteredit is triggered (which is technically right but not normal for a checkbox)

I tried clicksToEdit: 1 for the checkbox object but it doesn't seem to help.

I'm new to ExtJS and i'm working on an existing mature project which uses ExtJS version 3.2.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use a checkcolumn and get rid of the specifically defined editor/renderer.  Try following the example here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/edit-grid.html

Comment: i wish i could, checkcolumn isn't available in extjs 3.2.1. i tried using it already.

Comment: Ah. I would suggest either going the route of creating checkcolumn ( https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?17580-Click-event-on-CheckColumn&p=446019 ) or finding another way to change the value on cell click.  The problem right now is that it is showing your editor checkbox after activating the cell on the first click, which has to be clicked again.